# C++ how to pass N many arguments to a function at runtime

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, variadic-functions

**EDIT:**
The function is passed as argument and I can NOT change it.

**QUESTION:**
How can I use std::apply() in the scenario described below.
I get FUNC f, and int D as arguments and have to provide something like

```
std::tuple<int, int, ..., int> tuple_with_D_ints;
std::apply(f, tuple_with_D_ints);
```

or is `std::array<D, int>` already tuple-like as in sense of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply

---

I try to implement a function which takes the following arguments

```
template <FUNC>
compute_in_D_dims(int D, FUNC f, int N)
```

where

- D is the number of dimensions
- f is a provided function which will take D-many arguments f(x_1, ..., x_D) and return a double
- N is the ceiling of a sequence 0, ..., N-1

I wish to create permutations with repetitions for D many numbers from the sequence 0 to N-1

so with D = 3 it would look like

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
       for (int k = 0; k < N; ++k)
           f(i, j, k)
```

Now **D is provided as an argument and not known a priori**. Further, D could be large, which makes the writing of deep nested loops not really feasible.

I have the idea that for the permutations there exist a bijective mapping to a number I as I have exactly N^D many permutations and I could count through them.

Back in my example with D = 3, and N = 2 my permutations would look like

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
1 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
```

and

```
bijection(n) = // implement function
```

would return for the 5-th index (counting from 0)

```
bijection(5) = {1, 0, 1}
```

**So now the hard part:**

how do I pass my return tuple / vector / ... to the provided function?

It could be 2 elements or 10 elements and I have zero idea how to pass D-many arguments to the function. Further, as the function is given as an argument, I have no control over it.

I have heard the hints of "variadic functions" but I have zero idea what exactly it is and how to start.

Comment: There are two questions here, which one are you most interested in?  Also, what is the type of those `D` arguments and are they all the same type?

Comment: you can use eg a `std::vector<int>` to pass N integers to a function, or return from a function

Comment: Template instantiation is at compile time, always (that includes variadic functions). But you don't need it anyways, put you arguments in a nested vector instead. Run though that recursively.

Comment: @nick It can and should be done iteratively, in a single while/for loop. Depending on D and N values (N power D actually), a recursion would probably run out of stack. And it's easy to maintain a vector of parameters instead and "increment" it.

Comment: You can use `std::apply(f, arr)` to call `f` with values from `std::array<int, D> arr`. `D` is actually a template paramter, as it has to agree with the arity of `f`

Comment: `D` should be a template parameter.

Comment: It is not permutation but Cartesian product that you build.

Comment: how exactly is this comment helping me with the actual task?

Comment: It helps by allowing to search with correct term.

Comment: BTW, either `f` has fixed signature, so arity/`D` is compile-time, or `D` is runtime and `f` should take a vector-like argument.

Answer (score 1):

This is doable, but as commented it is not the best design.

### The Easy Way

We can take advantage of the fact that the function arity is a compile-time constant and is supposed to match the dimension, hence we actually already know `d` at compile time. The function trait here is pretty dumb, but can easily be extended to work for general callables.

```
template <typename Func>
struct FunctionArity;

template <typename R, typename... Ts>
struct FunctionArity<R(Ts...)>{
    static constexpr std::size_t value = sizeof...(Ts);
};
```

Once we effectively have the value `d` at compile time, the rest are trivial. We declare a `std::array` of the correct size, then fill it with the correct values and finally call `std::apply` on it.

```
template <typename Func>
auto compute_in_d_dims(int d, Func&& f, int n){
    constexpr std::size_t d0 = FunctionArity<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(f)>>::value;
    std::array<int, d0> args{};
    assert(d == d0);
    do{
        auto next_digit_iter = std::find_if(args.rbegin(), args.rend(), [n](auto&& v){
            if(v < n-1){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                v = 0;
                return false;
            }
        });
        if(next_digit_iter == args.rend()) break;
        (*next_digit_iter)++;
        std::apply(f, args);        
    }while(true);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EeYhdhxzG)

### The More Advanced Way

Now, the really interesting and challenging question is, can we do this without extracting the arity of the function? The above solution will not work, for example, if `f` is actually a function object with an overloaded call operator, i.e. something with more than one arities. In that case, "declaring the array to have the same dimension as the arity" just doesn't make sense.

The answer is, it is still possible. In the following I'll use c++20 instead of c++ 17 because the syntax is less clumsy.

First, we need to have a SFINAE-friendly version of the `compute_in_d_dims` that is templated on `d` (I'll use a captial `D` to emphasize it's a template parameter), and here is the code

```
template <typename, typename>
struct Applicable: std::false_type {};

template <typename Func, int... Is>
struct Applicable<Func, std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>>:
std::is_invocable<Func, decltype(Is)...> {};

template <typename Func, int D>
auto compute_in_d_dims_helper(Func&& f, int n){
    std::array<int, D> args{};
    do{
        //... (same as in the first section)
        if constexpr (Applicable<Func, std::make_integer_sequence<int, D>>::value)
            std::apply(f, args);  
        else
            assert(false);      
    }while(true);
}
```

`Applicable` is a SFINAE-friendly trait to check whether `Func` can be invoked with the given arity. We have to detour because `std::apply` itself is not SFINAE-friendly and will have a hard compile error if the types of `Func` and the rest of the arguments mismatch.

Next, we need to do a dispatch to convert the runtime parameter `d` to the compile time constant `D`. Traditionally this is done via a hard-coded switch like

```
switch(x){
    case 1:
       f<1>();
    case 2:
       f<2>();
    ....
}
```

and so on, but this quickly gets tedious. Fortunately, the compiler can generate such a switch for us, by utilizing `std::variant`.

First, let's define a variant type of `std::integral_constant`s;

```
template <typename>
struct MakeVariantHelper;

template <int... Is>
struct MakeVariantHelper<std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>>{
    using type = std::variant<std::integral_constant<int, Is>...>;
};

template <int N>
using MakeVariant = MakeVariantHelper<std::make_integer_sequence<int, N>>::type;
```

So for example `MakeVariant<2>` will expand to `std::variant<std::integral_constant<int, 0>, std::integral_constant<int, 1>>`. This is an important step: we are mapping the runtime `variant::index()` to a compile constant we can obtain from `std::integral_constant`.

Next, we use the fold expression to map the runtime `d` value to the index of the variant, which is then mapped to the `std::integral_constant`.

```
    constexpr int maxArity = 10;

    MakeVariant<maxArity-1> var;
    [&]<int...Is>(std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>){
        ((Is == d ? (var.emplace<Is>(), true): false) || ...);
    }(std::make_integer_sequence<int, maxArity-1>{});
```

The limitation here is that we need to have a `maxArity`, but that should not be a problem for most practical applications. If you really want to get aggressive, please follow Annex B of the C++ standard and set it to 256. Anything beyond 256 is not guaranteed to work on standard-conforming compilers.

Because `d` is already encoded as a compile time constant, the call to our helper function is just:

```
    std::visit([&]<int D>(std::integral_constant<int, D>){
        compute_in_d_dims_helper<Func, D>(std::forward<Func>(f), n);
    }, var);
```

Additionally, I am fully aware of the fact that for this simple case, it is not really necessary to use `std::variant` and `std::visit`, we could have just as well written

```
    [&]<int...Is>(std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>){
        ((Is == d ? (compute_in_d_dims_helper<Func, Is>(std::forward<Func>(f), n), true): false) || ...);
    }(std::make_integer_sequence<int, maxArity-1>{});
```

and call it a day. However, I do believe that the `variant` trick is useful in more complex situations.

[Demo with a function object that has a overloaded call operator](https://godbolt.org/z/d53afcbWx), [and without the variant](https://godbolt.org/z/ej1a1b9xf).

Finally, we can rearrange the code a bit to avoid unnecessary instantiations of the helper template. Just move the `constexpr` check to the `compute_in_d_dims` function like this: https://godbolt.org/z/PvKnq64fP